# How to find a number $n$ such that $\frac{n}{\phi(n)} > 10$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, recreational-mathematics

How to find a number $n$ such that $$\frac{n}{\phi(n)} > 10,$$ where $\phi(n)$ denotes the Euler's phi function?

I was trying to find the smallest one, so was keeping each prime once.
I tried with the number $$n = 2\times3\times5\times7\times11\times13\times17\times19$$ and some more numbers, but not working. Need some help!

Note that $$\phi(n) = n \times \prod_{p} \left(1-\frac1p \right) = n \times \prod_{p} \left(\frac{p-1}{p} \right)$$ hence
$$\frac{n}{\phi(n)} = \prod_{p} \left(\frac{p}{p-1} \right).$$

Comment: Just keep on multiplying with the next prime. It will take some time until you beat $10$, but eventually you will beat every given limit this way, and then you have also found the smallest number breaking the limit.

Comment: This is indeed the right approach, but it will take some work. If my computation is right, you have to take the product of primes all the way up to 257 for the quotient to exceed 10.

Comment: @Wojowu How did you find 257?

Comment: @user8795 I think this can only be determined (quickly) with a computer. Use one of the standard number theory tools like pari/gp or python.

Comment: For example in Mathematica ```primorial[n_?Positive] := Product[Prime[i], {i, 1, n}];Table[primorial[n]/EulerPhi[primorial[n]],{n,1,55}] //N```

Comment: I think $55$ primes suffice, [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N%5Bproduct%5B+%28prime%5Bn%5D-1%29%2F%28prime%5Bn%5D%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C55%7D%5D%5D)

Comment: The $55^{th}$ prime is indeed $257$.

Comment: Look at [A091439](http://oeis.org/A091439) for more info (not that there is much). This confirms what others have said about using the $55$th primorial.

Comment: [Here](https://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-69-find-the-value-of-n-%E2%89%A4-1000000-for-which-n%CF%86n-is-a-maximum/) is a webpage for doing this.

Comment: PARI/GP confirms $257$ to be the smallest prime doing the job. Code is (not very efficient however for larger values) : n=1;p=1;while(n/eulerphi(n)<=10,p=nextprime(p+1);n=n*p);print(p)

Comment: The number has already $104$ digits : $$16516447045902521732188973253623425320896207954043566485360902980990824644545340710198976591011245999110$$

Comment: And $n/\phi(n)=10.003719732091010383325131639818913973$ for this number.

Comment: I guess an interesting problem is does $\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac {p_k}{p_k-1}$ unbounded?  If not what is its upper limit.  I imagine using $\pi(x)\approx \frac x{\ln x}$ yields a way of answering that but I'm too unmotivated to work it out myself.  If the number is unbounded or at least not bounded by $10$ do we really care what the answer is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution in the comments, done by several people, is saying that, with
$f(n)=\frac{n}{\phi(n)}$ we have
$$
f(p_{55}\#)=10.003719732091010383325131639818913973
$$
where
$$
p_{55}\#=16516447045902521732188973253623425320896207954043566485360902980990824644545340710198976591011245999110
$$
and that this is the smallest such integer with $f(n)>10$.

More information is found in the following post, by considering $1/f(n)$:

[$\frac{\phi(m)}{m}$ is dense in $[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1850382/frac-phimm-is-dense-in-0-1?rq=1)

Comment: Note that it is nontrivial to prove that the "champion numbers" for $n/\phi(n).$ I think so; in any case, the champions for $\phi(n)$  are the primorials.  http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/petitsphiDPP.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The other answer covers the $x=10$ case, but I'll show that if you want $\frac n{\varphi(n)}>x$ for any real number $x$ that is always possible.

I'm going to use the notation

$$f(x)\sim g(x)\iff \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$$

It is unfortunately not standard. I lifted it from "An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers" by Hardy and Wright.

Mertens' third theorem tells us that

$$\prod_{p\leq a}1-\frac 1 p \sim \frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\ln(a)}$$

For a primorial $n$ we then have

$$\frac n{\varphi(n)}\sim\ln(a)e^\gamma$$

Since we want the quantity on the LHS to be greater than $x$ we need to $a$ to be approximately

$$a \sim\exp\left(e^{-\gamma}x\right)$$

This increases exponentially in $x$ which explains why the answer to your question is so big. For $x=10$ that gets you $a\approx 274$, close to the true value of 257.

Answer (score 0):

A more "manual" approach, [considering](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3615890?seq=1)
$$\log{(1+x)}\geq \frac{x}{1+x}, \forall x>-1$$
We can build an estimation as per the following:
$$\frac{n}{\varphi(n)}=
\prod\limits_{p}\frac{p}{p-1}=
\prod\limits_{p}\left(1+\frac{1}{p-1}\right)\geq
\prod\limits_{p} e^{\frac{\frac{1}{p-1}}{1+\frac{1}{p-1}}}=\\
\prod\limits_{p} e^{\frac{1}{p}}=e^{\sum\limits_{p}\frac{1}{p}}$$
or, we are forcing for
$$\sum\limits_{p}\frac{1}{p} \geq \log{10}$$
[But](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes)
$$\sum\limits_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p}\geq \log{\log{(x+1)}}-\log{\frac{\pi^2}{6}}$$
then forcing further for
$$\log{\log{(x+1)}} \geq\log{10}+ \log{\frac{\pi^2}{6}} \iff\\
\log{(x+1)}\geq 10\cdot\frac{\pi^2}{6} \iff \\
x \geq e^{10\cdot\frac{\pi^2}{6}} -1=13927008.866545...$$
reveals we have to consider all the primes between $1$ and $13927009$.

---

The crude estimates above can be fine tuned further, given
$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\sum _{p\leq x}{\frac {1}{p}}-\log \log x\right)=M\approx 0.261497...$$
for sufficiently large $x$
$$\sum _{p\leq x}{\frac {1}{p}} > \log \log x + \frac{M}{2}$$
then
$$x\geq e^{e^{\log{10} -\frac{M}{2}}}\approx 6466.46...$$